# 08P01: insufficient data left in message for Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have database table having one column defined as `timestamp without time zone`. Now from my c# application, when I try to insert null value in that column using `NpgSql BeginBinaryImport` it gives error message as mentioned below:

> 08P01: insufficient data left in message

Below is the code which I am trying to execute:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BulkInsert();
}

private static void BulkInsert()
{

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("firstname", typeof(String));
    table.Columns.Add("lastname", typeof(String));
    table.Columns.Add("logdatetime", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Columns.Add("status", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(long));

    var dataRow = table.NewRow();
    dataRow["firstname"] = "MyFirstName";
    dataRow["lastname"] = "MyLastName";
    dataRow["logdatetime"] = DBNull.Value;
    dataRow["status"] = 1;
    dataRow["id"] = 10;
    table.Rows.Add(dataRow);

    var data = new DataAccess();

    using (var npgsqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection([ConnectionString]))
    {
        npgsqlConn.Open();
        var commandFormat = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "COPY {0} {1} FROM STDIN BINARY", "logging.testtable", "(firstName,LastName,logdatetime,status,id)");
        using (var writer = npgsqlConn.BeginBinaryImport(commandFormat))
        {
            foreach (DataRow item in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                writer.StartRow();
                foreach (var item1 in item.ItemArray)
                {
                     writer.Write(item1);
                }

            }
        }

        npgsqlConn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the `DBNull.Value` you're trying to write - Npgsql doesn't support writing nulls this way. To write a null you need to use the `WriteNull()` method instead.

I can make Npgsql accept `DBNull.Value`, but only for the overload of `Write()` which also accepts an NpgsqlDbType (because Npgsql has to write the data type, and with `DBNull.Value` we have no idea what that is).

**EDIT:** Have done this, see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1122.

Comment: Note that as part of https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1465 you can now pass `DBNull.Value` even without an NpgsqlDbType.

Comment: Is there any alternative for importing data using BeginRawBinaryCopy. Here, while writing we need to pass byte array. Seems that for byte array NullCheck is not feasible.
Please suggest if any alternative. @shay-rojansky

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue while bulk copying data in table. To solve this I have created an extension method so you dont have to null check on all fields

```
public static void WriteWithNullCheck(this NpgsqlBinaryImporter writer, string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(value);
            }
        }
```

this can be made generic by

```
public static void WriteWithNullCheck<T>(this NpgsqlBinaryImporter writer, T value,NpgsqlDbType type)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(value, type);
            }
        }
```